# Examples of going from an $\mathbb{F}G$-module to a representation.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am reading Gordon James and Martin Liebeck's "Representations and Characters of Groups." In chapter 4 they have a theorem that states:

"Assume that $V$ is an $FG$-module and let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis of $V$ then the function $g \longrightarrow [g]_{\mathcal{B}}$ is a representation of $G$ over $F$"

(here $g \in G$).

I was wondering if someone could provide some examples of this, particularly of how to map $g$ to $[g]_{\mathcal{B}}?$ I might have a notational misunderstanding, but this seems like it would map everything to a vector not a matrix? I am also not seeing how this maps to square matrices? Seeing some examples would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Just take the action of $S_n$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by permuting the standard basis. Then any permutation $\sigma$ maps to the elementary matrix $E$ such that left multiplication $E\mapsto EA$ permutes the rows of the matrix $A$ according to $\sigma$ (equivalently it permutes the entries of a vector in $\Mathbb{R}^n$). You can easily write these down for $n=2,3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is weird, in particular I don't really understand why the choice of basis matters. Maybe it is for representing linear maps as matrices only?

Anyway if $V$ is a $FG$-module then it induces the following representation:

$$\varphi:G\to GL(V)$$
$$\varphi(g)(v)=gv$$

and vice versa: a representation $\varphi:G\to GL(V)$ induces a $FG$-module structure on $V$ via

$$\bigg(\sum\lambda_ig_i\bigg)\cdot v:=\sum\lambda_i\varphi(g_i)(v)$$

Here $GL(V)$ denotes the group of all invertible linear maps $V\to V$. If $V$ is finite dimensional, then by fixing a basis we can represent these as matrices. This is the only reasonable way to go from $FG$-modules to representations and back.

Comment: the choice of basis matters because for James and Liebeck a rep is a homomorphism $\rho : G \to GL_n(F)$ for some $n$.